# Testing shared web workers like regular scripts with jest

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, web-worker

I'd like to implement and test shared web workers for a React application and after some researches I came on [jsdom-worker](https://github.com/developit/jsdom-worker) which seems to be one of the common ways to test web workers with jest.

However, this library is [not obvious to use with webpack](https://github.com/developit/jsdom-worker/issues/14) as configured by React CRA and it doesn't support shared web workers.

After more researches and trying a few things, I am wondering what are the downsides of testing web workers (shared of not) as "regular" scripts just mocking their environment.

Consider for instance this very basic shared web worker (written in typescript):

```js
const self = globalThis as unknown as SharedWorkerGlobalScope;

self.onconnect = function (e) {
  var port = e.ports[0];

  port.onmessage = function (e) {
    console.log(`Worker received ${JSON.stringify(e)}`);
    port.postMessage('pong');
  };

};
```

To test it we could export its global scope adding:

```js
export default self;
```

and a test suite could be (written in plain Javascript to keep things simple):

```js
import worker from './worker';

describe('The worker ', () => {
  let port;
  beforeEach(() => {
    port = {
      postMessage: jest.fn(),
    };
    worker.onconnect({ ports: [port] });
  });
  test('creates a onmessage function', () => {
    expect(port.onmessage).toBeDefined();
    expect(port.postMessage).not.toBeCalled();
  });
  test('receives a ping and sends a pong', () => {
    port.onmessage('ping');
    expect(port.postMessage).toBeCalledWith('pong');
  });
});
```

What would be the downsides of this approach and do we really need libraries such as jsdom-worker for unit tests (even though they should be really useful for integration tests) ?